# Startposition of Textbox Cursor

Tags: c#, wpf

I would like to increase the distance between the textbox border and the textbox cursor.

It should not move the cursor relative to the text in the textbox but simply change the appearance of the cursor. In Html it would be the left margin between textbox and textbox cursor.

I have no clue where to start.. any hint / help?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you want to do, just add a padding left to your TextBox like this :

```
<TextBox Padding="15, 0, 0, 0"/>
```